# Diffrence between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which is one of them is 
`AI: Ascent insensitive` and other is  `AS: Ascent sensitive`

How can I compare between them and take difference between them? I used `except`

```
select  ID,FIRST,FATHER,GRAND  from t1

EXCEPT

select ID,FIRST,FATHER,GRAND  from t2
```

But I got this error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Arabic_CI_AS" and
>   "Arabic_100_CI_AI" in the EXCEPT operation

Comment: you  have to "convert" the collation of one of the tables in the select statement using `collation <collation name>` after each selected column

Comment: like this collation(Arabic_CI_AS name ) ?

Comment: To find collation you can use SELECT *, COLLATION_NAME FROM SYS.COLUMNS WHERE OBJECT_ID IN
(
 SELECT OBJECT_ID FROM SYS.OBJECTS WHERE TYPE='U' AND NAME='T1'
)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH I APPRECIATE IT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose an appropriate collation so that the comparison of the strings does match as wanted (e. G. "CI" = case sensitive/insensitive), the use your collation like this (ignoring the problem of of the `ID` column in `EXCEPT`:

```
select  ID,
        FIRST  collate Arabic_CI_AS,
        FATHER collate Arabic_CI_AS,
        GRAND  collate Arabic_CI_AS
from t1

EXCEPT

select ID,
       FIRST  collate Arabic_CI_AS,
       FATHER collate Arabic_CI_AS,
       GRAND  collate Arabic_CI_AS
from t2
```

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH IT WORKED GREAT

Answer (score 0):

it working here

[image]

USE [TestDb]
GO

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FIRST] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [FATHER] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [GRAND] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_t1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FIRST] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [FATHER] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [GRAND] [nchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_t2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: I am not sure if the test works in your case because of the newly created tables are living in the same database. Normally you have to specify a different than the DB default collation explicitly when you create a table (which I cannot see in your scripts above and could mean that both tables use the same collation): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-column-collation